# Compilation Warning.Excess elements in array initializer

Tags: c, pointers, multidimensional-array, compiler-errors, compiler-warnings

I was implementing a multi dimensional array and using pointers and testing the correctness of the address allotment.Even though the program ran perfectly and all the addresses were same as i expected.But there was a compilation warning `[Warning] excess elements in array initializer`.Can anyone explain about the warning.The code is below....

```
#include<stdio.h>
    int main(){
    int c[3][2][2] = {{{2,5},{7,9},{3,4},{6,1},{0,8},{11,13}}};
    printf("%d %d %d %d",c,*c,c[0],&c[0][0]);
    return 0;
}
```

The error summary is like this

```
        In function 'main':
3   2   [Warning] excess elements in array initializer
3   2   [Warning] (near initialization for 'c[0]')
3   2   [Warning] excess elements in array initializer
3   2   [Warning] (near initialization for 'c[0]')
3   2   [Warning] excess elements in array initializer
3   2   [Warning] (near initialization for 'c[0]')
3   2   [Warning] excess elements in array initializer
3   2   [Warning] (near initialization for 'c[0]')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have three pairs of a pair of `int`s. The initialization should be:

```
int c[3][2][2] = {{{2,5},{7,9}},{{3,4},{6,1}},{{0,8},{11,13}}};
      3                 ^             ^             ^
         2           ^     ^
            2       ^ ^
```

Comment: Worked !! But can you explain the warning.

Comment: @SaiKiranUppu The brackets were not correct for the specified dimensions. That is it.

Comment: Can you please explain i cant figure out what your answer is

Comment: That's not three pairs of two ints; a "pair of two ints" has only two ints. You were right in your original wording (edited out in the grace period).

Comment: @user2357112 I agree it was ambiguous, so I made it clearer.

Answer (score 1):

That is not a three dimensional array. You forgot a brace!

```
int c[3][2][2] = {{{2,5},{7,9}},{{3,4},{6,1}},{{0,8},{11,13}}};
```

Perhaps reformat things to make it clearer:

```
int c[3][2][2] = {
    { {2,5}, {7,9} }, 
    { {3,4}, {6,1} },
    { {0,8}, {11,13} }
};
```

Comment: Your new initializer is for a 2x3x2 array, not 3x2x2.

Comment: @user2357112 Thanks, it seems I can't count.